# Swift 3 getting an optional value from objective-c class?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I have a project that still has a lot of objective-c code, like this one:

```
+ (NSString *)getDaysFromDateString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    // Creating and configuring date formatter instance
    NSLocale *ptBRLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:ptBRLocale];

    // Retrieve NSDate instance from stringified date presentation
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    // Retrieve date with increased days count
    NSDate *newDate = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-30*24*60*60];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
}
```

This was working fine with my Swift 2.2 project (this project has both Swift and Objective-c) and always returned a value. Now, I have migrated my code to Swift 3.0 and for some reason the method above returns an optional value. How can I make the code above return a non-optional value again?

Comment: Use "_Nonnull": https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: @EricAya Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.